# Sending data through Link tag in next js

Tags: next.js

I'm passing a state data to the redirected page using Link tags in next js.

From home page I'm redirecting to course page with *courseData* in **state**.

```
<Link href={{pathname: '/course', state: {courseData}}}>
   <a>Link</a>
</Link>
```

And in the course page when I access props.location and I get undefined:

```
function course(props) {
   console.log(props.location) //undefined
}
```

Is this the right way to send the state and receive in props?

Answer (score 1):

Currently that's not possible to pass state using Links.

You can pass string value with query param

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={{ pathname: '/course', query: { keyword: 'string value' } }}>
    <a>path</a>
</Link>

<Link href="/post/abc?foo=bar">
    <a>path</a>
</Link>
```

Also you can save any required state in localStorage, sessionStorage, a variable, a Redux store, etc. and then use it in getInitialProps

Comment: Sending in query is possible. But, the data will be seen in url which is not expected.